# May I know the second request came in if I use synchronized?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a method that is called in a controller.
for example,
`public AnyObject do(String name, String do) {...}`

I want it to be impossible to execute this method for the same name.
I do:
`public AnyObject do(String name, String do) { Name people = nameRepository.findByName(name);     synchronized (people) {...} }`

I hope my thoughts are correct...

And if during the execution of the method it happens to be called again for "people", I want to throw an exception. How can I know that the object is currently busy?

I did not find any options to find out that the object is currently busy.

Comment: With `synchronized`, we do not have the capability to throw an exception, we can only wait until the resource gets available. If we need more fine-grained control, we can use a [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html). --- Why do you want to throw an exception instead of waiting until the resource is available?

Comment: What's the point of synchronizing on `people` if the second thread throws an exception before it even gets there?

Comment: I want to catch the exception in ExceptionHandler and  alert the user who initiated the request to wait.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a set of processing names and throw an exception if your name is already there:

```
private final Set<String> processingNames =
        Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());

public AnyObject do(String name, String do) {
    if (!processingNames.add(name)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(name + " already processing");
    }
    try {
        Name people = nameRepository.findByName(name);
        synchronized (people) {
            //...
        }
    } finally {
        processingNames.remove(name);
    }
}
```